# Handling "no data" scenario with Flow Router and Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, router

I'm wondering how to handle the "no data" scenario with the Meteor's Flow Router. Let's say I want to have a route `/article/:slug` on which I want to render an Article (fetched by the `slug` field) along with related comments (separate collection). So I'll define a route like this:

```
FlowRouter.route('/article/:slug', {
  subscriptions: function(params) {
    this.register('article', Meteor.subscribe('articleSlug', params.slug));
    this.register('comments', Meteor.subscribe('commentsByArticleSlug', params.slug));
  },
  action: function() {
    FlowLayout.render('appLayout', { main: "articleDetail" });
  }
});
```

In the template I'll display the article details & comments when subs are ready, until then I'll just display a "loading..." text.

But what if the `:slug` param in the URL doesn't match any article in the DB? I don't want to keep displaying the "loading..." text, I want to display some sort of "Article not found" message. How to do this?

Thanks for any advice.

UPDATE: I'd also like to point to the github discussion related to this question: https://github.com/meteorhacks/flow-router/issues/70

Answer (score 3):

This could be done by your template.

```
Template.articleDetail.helpers ({
   articleFound: articles.find().count() > 0
});
```

In your **view**, render the right stuff depends on result of **articleFound**.

Comment: I wonder what is the fastest way: `!!(articles.find().count())` or `!!(articles.findOne())`...

Comment: i guess !!(articles.find().count())

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an official answer, but it's what I'd do. Let's say this is for a blog (looks that way) you can just throw a conditional there, similar to a 404.

So

```
subscriptions: function(params) {
    //check that this slug has an article assigned to it
    var slugCheck = Meteor.subscribe('articleSlug', params.slug);

    if (slugCheck != ''){
        this.register('article', Meteor.subscribe('articleSlug', params.slug));
        this.register('comments', Meteor.subscribe('commentsByArticleSlug', params.slug));
    }
    else{
        this.register('article', Meteor.subscribe('articleSlug', 'missing'));
    }
}
```

Then you'd just need to show the missing article entry.

Comment: What if there's an invalid slug, as the question mentioned?

Comment: I see, I answered a different questions didn't I? In that case I would store my query as a variable before registering. I've updated my answer. Logic could also be if (slugCheck){ // do something}

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for both answers! While testing them I came up with a third way: leave the subs in the `subscriptions` section and put the check to the `action` section - there we can do redirect if no article fit the slug.

```
FlowRouter.route('/article/:slug', {
  subscriptions: function(params) {
    this.register('article', Meteor.subscribe('articleSlug', params.slug));
    this.register('comments', Meteor.subscribe('commentsByArticleSlug', params.slug));
  },
  action: function() {
    if (Articles.find().count() > 0) {
      FlowLayout.render('appLayout', { main: "articleDetail" });
    }
    else {
      FlowRouter.go('/articlenotfound');
    }
  }
});
```